# How to open a pdf in full screen mode by command line?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way how to open a pdf file by using command line of Adobe and Foxit or windows.

Note: it's not a double topic of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557920/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-fullscreen-view-via-command-line because the marked answer does not works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Before using command line just open the program AcroRd32.exe/Acrobat.exe and go to `Edit=> preferences=> Full Screen` and un-tick on `Current document` only, then you can use the command line as:

`start "" /max "C:\Program Files Xxxxx.exe" /A "pagemode=FullScreen" "yourfile direction and name.pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

For Foxit Reader, the command would be:
`"[path_to_executable]Foxit Reader.exe" <path_to_your_pdf>`. For example, on my Windows the command is: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" C:\Users\Paulius\Desktop\mcs.pdf`.

I don't have Adobe Reader to test but I believe the same command (different executable) should work.

Comment: and how to it open in full screen mode?

Comment: It looks like there is no official support for this in Foxit Reader.